# Resize div to fit portrait mode

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design

Hellow I have a problem with my website.
I'm coding responsive layout and I have problem with portrait mode.
My site is here - www.szafortest.pl

You can check css and html code in webbrowser. If You want I can put code here.
My problem is that I have big white margin. Please refer to image below.
[image]

What I would like to do is to resize "textContent" class. I tried using viewport but always I can find device which will display this site badly.

Do You know any good solution for it?

Comment: Have you looked at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)?

Answer (score 0):

As James Newton suggested in the comments, you could use `flexbox` to solve this problem. I have a library which allows me to position elements in rows and columns with flexbox. They are named `flex-row` and `flex-column`. The names should speak for itself. There is one more important class called `autoflex`. It allows me to fill the remaining space of a div or size divs evenly. This is a solution you could try:
HTML:

```
<body class="flex-column">
    <div class="yourContent"></div>
    <div class="autoflex"></div> <!--This will fill all whitespace -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-column {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;  
}

.flex-row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;  
}

.autoflex {
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

**EDIT**
These classes are only supporting standard and webkit browsers. To make this more compatible with other browsers, you should add `-moz-flex` for example to the properties.